Automatically redirect into /login, when i do npm run dev wherever filepath
When i do npm run dev for my Nextjs file automatically redirect into /login whatever my filepath, even i make new next.js file. This happend after i did git clone a file from my internship, but i don't know exactly. I was searching for the problem like about Service worker, but still doesn't work.
`> my-app@0.1.0 dev

next dev

▲ Next.js 15.0.2

Local:        http://localhost:3000

✓ Starting...
✓ Ready in 1555ms
○ Compiling /_not-found ...
✓ Compiled /_not-found in 2.7s (569 modules)
GET /login 404 in 3016ms
✓ Compiled in 101ms (279 modules)
GET /login 404 in 37ms
○ Compiling /favicon.ico ...
✓ Compiled /favicon.ico in 511ms (313 modules)
GET /favicon.ico 200 in 627ms`
Network
Network detail
Sorry i just beginner developer.
I was searching for the problem like about Service worker, but still doesn't work. I expect it is from my a npm folder, service worker, or the network detail that i don't know what to do.

If there is any custom redirect setup in the next.config.js/ts file, it could cause automatic redirects. Look for any configuration related to redirects, rewrites, or headers.
For example
    module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/old-path',
        destination: '/new-path',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};

Additionally you should check for middlleware file usually named middlware.js or middlleware.ts and then confirm if there are no redirects there.
